# FabricJS Center/Scroll div viewportTransform

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs, viewport

Im working in an app that uses fabricjs for a canvas. It has some user panels on the sides and a canvas in the middle. The main idea is to have a big working area and a smaller exportable area in the center. That way, the user can have shapes outside the exportable area and only export a small part of the canvas. Kinda like powerpoint were you have a white exportable area and a gray working area.
[image: Powerpoint view]

For that, i use viewporTransform of fabricjs that enables that functionality. It works, but im having trouble with the scrolling, so the white area is "centered" or "scrolled" both x-y so the user opens the app and the white area is in the middle of the screen, but has gray area on the sides that can be scrolled. Right now, the view is started at (0,0) so the white area is not visible. How can i autoscroll to that area?

**Example**: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1gfmxza/)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  width: 1000,
  height: 1000,
  backgroundColor: "gray"
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  fill: 'white',
  evented: false,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  noScaleCache: false
});

canvas.setBackgroundImage(rect);
canvas.viewportTransform = [1, 0, 0, 1, 375, 375];

canvas.add(
  new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    fill: 'yellow',
    angle: 30
  }));

canvas.renderAll();
```

In the example, there is a white exportable area, a big gray canvas and a yellow rectangle that can be anywhere in the canvas, but only the parts over the white area are exported in the final SVG.

Since the canvas has the "overflow" and not the page/app, i cant use window.scrollTo(). canvas.relativePan(x,y) pans the canvas but removes the panned area so is also not an option.

So, the main idea is to have like powerpoint. When you open a ppt, you have a white exportable area in the middle, and if you move a shape to to the sides (or zoom out), you have a gray working area that is not showed on the final ppt.

**JSFiddle current view**
[image: JSFiddle current view]

**Expected starting view**
[image: Expected starting view]

How do i make my white area to be in the middle of the app/view when i open it?
Thanks